# xlim for bar plot does not work the same as for plot

Tags: matlab

I am trying to set the x-axis limits of a bar chart.

When doing the following for a plot it works fine:

```
plot(dates, y); datetick;
xlim([dates(5), dates(10)]);
```

However when I do the following:

```
bar(dates, y); datetick;
xlim([dates(5), dates(10)]);
```

Then I get a figure where the y axis have also been affected. Here are the figure outputs:

[image: Correct display with plot]

[image: Wrong display with bar]

---

**SAMPLE**

Here is a sample file (first column dates, second column values). [Download here the .mat file](https://filebin.net/221mqdjvw32fybuf).

I apply the following function to the plot:

```
bar(x(:,1), x(:,2)); datetick; % when you do plot(...) it works
applyLimitsToGraph(x(:,1), x(:,2))

function applyLimitsToGraph(dates, Z)
% Apply NaN limits to a graph

firstNAN = find(sum(isnan(Z),2)~=size(Z,2),1,'first');
lastNAN  = find(sum(isnan(Z),2)~=size(Z,2),1,'last');
xlim([dates(firstNAN), dates(lastNAN)])

end
```

Comment: how do dates and y are initialized?

Comment: Y is a M x N matrix with NaNs and Values. dates is a datenum vector of M x 1 size.

Comment: what are M and N?\

Comment: I added a sample .mat file with the data. And also the exact code see SAMPLE in my updated question.

Comment: ? I have provided you with two examples of code and in addition added a sample dataset (.mat) that you can use to replicate the problem I am facing. I cannot put my dataset in the code?

Comment: I am unable to provide you how I got the variables as it is from a different source. When I gen random data I do not have this problem, but I do on this dataset.